# Analytical Mechanics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, acceleration, speed

[image]

I see  that 
$W_a(1) = \dot U_a(1)=\ddot{X_a}(1) = 0.3 $

Since $U_{O'}=0 $ then O' is Instant centre of rotation. Then $U_b = 2U_a = 0.6$

I tried a lot, about a week, i find the speed, but there is a problem with acceleration. I know that we can find the acceleration using projections. But i don't understand what to do with $\varepsilon$. (Angular acceleration).
Help me please.

I mean, that for points B, C i can find ${W_b}_n  = OB*\omega_{ob}^2 , {W_c}_n = OC*\omega_{oc}^2$, because it simple to find $\omega_{ob},\omega_{ob}$ when you have $U_C, U_B,U_A$. But it hard for me to find ${W_b}_\tau  = OB*\varepsilon_{ob} , {W_c}_\tau = OC*\varepsilon_{oc}$.  I also don't know their directions.

[image]

I have 4 A4 papers with attempts but  i very slow in LaTeX and English too.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean you don't know what to do with epsilon(angular acceleration) ? Remember the crucial equation that:

translational acceleration = angular acceleration * distance to rotational axis

a = epsilon*r. Otherwise I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: I added more information, thank you for responding

Comment: hmmm... look you have the force at point B, great news, force carries information about the tangential acceleration. F = m*a, a = OB*epsilon. so if you have Wbt you have the answer. (I am too lazy for latex too :) )

Comment: There isn't m. We look at B as a point.

Comment: Full $A = Wb = \sqrt{W_{b\tau}^2+W_{bn}^2}$

Comment: oh ok A is acceleration, (normally small a). can you tell me what is given? is Wbr or Wbn or Wc given ? or did you calculate any of them ?

Comment: Wbn we can find

Comment: I mean if you have any of those accelerations, you can find (through vector analysis) the others. If you can find Wbt then your epsilon = Wbt/OB

Comment: Other order. I can't find Wbt because i don't know \varepsilon. If i know \vareepsilon - > i know Wbt -> i solve problem

Comment: but you have omega! you have omega and you have delta time,
delta_t = 1 (at t = 1 s). Meaning epsilon is the change of speed w.r.t time. omega you can express in terms of s(t) (because it is the change of displacement over time). I would like to solve it on paper and then post it later at night

Comment: I think its not true, because of changing BC (it is rotating)

Comment: I dont understand the problem that much because there is no solid question, I am just telling you, you have so much information you can use there, you just have to think systematically. If you are still stuck on the question post me an update and I will try it later tonight

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19256/discussion-between-engin007-and-slmkarta).